# T-SQL calculation with a CASE statement isn't working

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm scratching my head over this. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm stumped. I have the following T-SQL, which I'm running in SQL Server 2012:

```
DECLARE @MAX_naam AS varchar(MAX) = (SELECT SUBSTRING(MAX(naam),LEN(MAX(naam))-1,LEN(MAX(naam))) FROM incident); -- = 22
DECLARE @maxnaam_length AS int = LEN(@MAX_naam);
DECLARE @num_zeroes AS int = 5 - @maxnaam_length;
DECLARE @zeroes AS varchar = 
    CASE WHEN @num_zeroes = 0 THEN ''
    WHEN @num_zeroes = 1 THEN '0'
    WHEN @num_zeroes = 2 THEN '00'
    WHEN @num_zeroes = 3 THEN '000'
    ELSE '' END;
select @zeroes
```

@MAX_naam is currently 22. @maxnaam_length is, correctly 2, and @num_zeroes is 3. I've verified each of these. However, despite expecting @zeroes to be '000', it comes out as '0'. Why?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Your `@zeroes` is now defined as a ***1 character long*** `varchar`  variable .... so assigning *any* string to it will only store the very first character - a single `0` in your case.....

Comment: Because your `@zeroes` variable has a length of 1 char.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @zeroes AS varchar = ...
```

Should be

```
DECLARE @zeroes varchar(11) = ...
---- important --------^^^^
```

For more info see [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: OK, you're right. However, when I change my code to DECLARE zeroes AS varchar(11) I get the same result. zeroes = '0'

Comment: @Melanie [i can’t reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a0f533c8f7de8374d69f10d5595be10c).

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a size for your @zeroes variable

```
DECLARE @zeroes AS varchar(64) = ...
```

In my case this resulted in the string `000`.

Comment: OK, you're right. However, when I change my code to DECLARE zeroes AS varchar(64) I get the same result. zeroes = '0'